# I am not able to share website url with dynamic ID on whatsapp

Tags: php, model-view-controller, whatsapp

I am fetching current URL which is having 1 dynamic id.
When I am trying to print the fetched URL than its proper.
But when I am going to share it on WhatsApp via WhatsApp API link then dynamic id from the URL is not fetching.

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo "<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=$actual_link' data-action='share/whatsapp/share'>Whatsapp</a>"; ?>
```

Structure MVC

Comment: To my understanding Whatsapp does not have a public API that can be used in this fashion. Do you have API credentials? For details see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's probably not working is because you are putting a URL in a URL. Try to `urlencode` your link variable first:

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo "<a href='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" . urlencode($actual_link) . "' data-action='share/whatsapp/share'>Whatsapp</a>"; ?>
```